# How to map custom data structures to bean entities with JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, data-structures

We have a (possibly large) custom data structure implemented in Java (8+). It has a simple and optimal API for querying pieces of data. The logical structure is roughly similar to an RDMS (it has e. g. relations, columns, primary keys, and foreign keys), but there is no SQL driver.

The main goal is to access the data via ORM (mapping logical entities to JPA annotated beans). It would be nice if we could use JPQL. Hibernate is preferred but other alternatives are welcome too.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? Which are the key parts of such an implementation?

(P. S. Directly implementing `SessionImplementor`, `EntityManagerImplementor` etc. seems to be too complicated.)

Comment: If it has an API to query already, what is the motivation to use an ORM to query?

Comment: @SreeKumar For making it JPA accessible. It could be an alternative driver for existing JPA frameworks and applications.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities.

Implement a JDBC compliant driver for your system, so you can use a JPA implementation such as Hibernate "directly" (although you may need to create a custom dialect for your system).

Program directly against the JPA specification like [ObjectDB](https://www.objectdb.com/) does, which bypasses the need to go through SQL and JPA implementations completely.

The latter one is probably easier, but you'd still need to implement the full JPA API. If it's a custom in-house-only system, there's very little sense in doing either one.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I thought up just now, that I feel may work is this:

1. Use an existing database implementation like H2 and use the JPA integration with that. H2 already has a JPA integration libraries, so it should be easy.
2. In this database, create a Java stored procedure or function and call it from your current application through JPA. See [this H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) on how to create a Java stored procedure or function. (You may want to explore the section "Using a Function as a Table" also.)
3. Define a protocol for the service methods and encapsulate it in a model class. An instance of this model class may be passed to the function/SP and responses retrieved.

**Caveat**: I have never done this myself but I think it will work.

---

**Edit**: Here is a diagram representing the thought. Though the diagram show H2 separately, it will most probably be in the same JVM as "Your Java/JEE application". However, since it is not necessary to use H2, I have shown it as as separate entity.

[image]